# C#: passing a method with variable parameters as parameter of another method

Tags: c#

So here I'm trying to pass a method with a random signature to Foo method. But without any luck.
The thing is that I can pass any action. But on a method.
Any help?

```
class Bar
{
    void M1(int a) { }
    void M2(string a, int b) { }

    Action<string, int, bool> A1 = (s, i, b) => {};
    Action<int, float> A2 = (i, f) => {};

    void Foo(Delegate f) {}

    void Test()
    {
        Foo(A1);
        Foo(A2);
        // Foo(M1); // nope
        // Foo(M2); // no way
    }
}
```

PS. I'm trying to get this working under Unity3d's Mono.

Comment: This is not specific to unity3d or mono, it's just part of the language. `M1` and `M2` are "method groups" not delegates. A method group can be converted to any compatible delegate type, and the the compiler refuses to pick one out of the air (like the `Action` or `Func` types).

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just mentioned it in case someone suggests the solution based on unique features of C# 3.0+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cast to concrete delegate type to do that, like this:

```
void Test()
{
    Foo(A1);
    Foo(A2);
    Foo((Action<int>) M1);
    Foo((Action<string, int>)M2); 
}
```

The reason for this is `M1` and `M2` are what is called method groups. That just means they refer to one or more methods. Why it can be more than one? Because you might have multiple methods with name M1, each of which accepts different set of arguments. But, even if you have just one overload, like in your case, there might be multiple delegate types compatible with that overload signature (that might be `Action<int>` or `YourDelegateType` which is declared as delegate void YourDelegateType(int arg), or whatever else).

That is why there is no implicit conversion from method group to delegate, and you have to cast method group to specific delegate type explicitly.

Comment: One thing is that multiple overloads may exist. But in this case, each of the names `M1` and `M2` has only one overload. Another thing is that multiple compatible concrete delegate types may exist. For example, with `void M3(object a, int b) { }` (just this single overload), the call `Foo(M3);` could stand for either `Foo((Action<object, int>)M3);` or `Foo((EventHandler<int>)M3);`. Or even `Foo((MyDel)M3);` where `MyDel` is some type you create yourself. The `Action<,>` does not have a special status in C#, so the compiler will not pick `Action<,>` "out of nothing".

Comment: Also, because co- and contravariance are possible with method group conversions, you can sometimes use another set of type parameters. Continuing my example from before, both `Foo((Action<object, int>)M3);` and `Foo((Action<Uri, int>)M3);` are possible.

Comment: Good points indeed. With that it's clear that there is no way to convert method group to delegate without explicitly choosing delegate type, even if just one overload exists.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution. It fully satisfies me.